# Azure Data Factory HTTP Dataset using Python SDK , unable to find parameters

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a HTTP 'Dataset' in Data Factory using Python SDK azure.mgmt.datafactory.models. I am unable to find the parameters in Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.httpdataset?view=azure-python) that will provide me the below features that I can see when created manually from portal.

Manual creation (from portal):

Create HTTP Dataset -> Select Format (Excel) -> I get the below page which has additional details -
'Worksheet mode', 'Sheet name', 'First row as header' etc.

Could you please point me to the right documentation/details to add these parameters?

From the link above, the relevant parameters I could fine are linked_service_name and Format (and in Format, I cannot see Excel there, but during manual creation I do see Excel)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ExcelDataset Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.exceldataset?view=azure-python) not HttpDataset Class. And pass your http linked service reference to ExcelDataset().

Here is my test code, you can have a try:

```
hl_name = 'HttpServer1'
ds_name = 'http_excel2'
ds_ls = LinkedServiceReference(reference_name=hl_name)
ds_http_excel = DatasetResource(properties=ExcelDataset(linked_service_name=ds_ls,sheet_name='sheet1',first_row_as_header=True))
ds = adf_client.datasets.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ds_name, ds_http_excel)
```

Result:
[image]